# Steam doesn't open on Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: lubuntu, 15.10, steam

So I'm a newbie to Linux in general and installed Steam on a VM to sort of test it out. I installed Steam to check what games are available in Linux and stuff but I just doesn't open. I double click the desktop icon and nothing happens.

I downloaded it from Steam's website and installed the package normally.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
pci id for fd 7: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

***EDIT:*** New problem. Now when I start Steam, the little update box appears for a couple of seconds and the terminal gives me this error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
pci id for fd 7: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
pci id for fd 23: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
[0417/235119:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0417/235119:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(203)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[0417/235119:INFO:audio_manager_pulse.cc(257)] Failed to connect to the context.  Error: Conexão recusada
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160331191033)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1459451433)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160331191033)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1459463254)
[0417/235119:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(777)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
PulseAudio connect failed (used only for Mic Volume Control) with error: Acesso negado
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
LLVM ERROR: Do not know how to split the result of this operator!

Bad thread local../common/steamservice.cpp (56) : Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL
Assert( Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL ):../common/steamservice.cpp:56

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1459463254)
crash_20160417235121_14.dmp[11509]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20160417235121_14.dmp
assert_20160417235115_1.dmp[11512]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20160417235115_1.dmp
/home/samuel/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: linha 756: 11447 Falha de segmentação  (imagem do núcleo gravada) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
assert_20160417235115_1.dmp[11512]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20160417235115_1.dmp[11512]: response: CrashID=bp-a7caa2ab-6060-4faf-82af-76e8d2160417
assert_20160417235115_1.dmp[11512]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160417235115_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-a7caa2ab-6060-4faf-82af-76e8d2160417''
crash_20160417235121_14.dmp[11509]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20160417235121_14.dmp[11509]: response: CrashID=bp-e70cd50a-debb-4a3e-80cd-e28b92160417
crash_20160417235121_14.dmp[11509]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20160417235121_14.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-e70cd50a-debb-4a3e-80cd-e28b92160417''
```

Comment: Open a terminal and run stam from there by `steam` and then add the output into your main post.

Comment: @Videonauth Could you ELI5 please? Sorry

Comment: Ok, first you press ctrl+alt+t on your keyboard, this will open a terminal window for you, then there you type in `steam` which will then result in steam trying to launch. if it fails it will print in this terminal window some output which you can copy by marking it with your mouse and pressing ctrl+shift+c. This output you can add then to your question putting it in `<pre></pre>` tags

Comment: @Videonauth Here is the result on pastebin since I apparently can't format it to code here:

http://pastebin.com/rbTDQ5Y4

Comment: @psusi Yeah, I found the solution there. Thanks!

Comment: I've got a new error. Look at the post above.